# Permanently apply ColorFilter to Bitmap.image regarding performance

Tags: html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

1. I have a canvas/stage with a big background image
2. I have a shape where i draw strokes on on stagemousemove
3. I have applied a AlphaMaskFilter to the background image with shape.cacheCanvas

This works fine. My Bitmap is only shown where i "paint" my shape including stokes not only fills. Fine.

Now i need to have the background texture to be of a specific color - at the moment it is a PNG with color all white and alpha so that it gives a rough texture like chalk.

Now i apply with the AlphaMaskFilter a ColorFilter to set the image to red or any color.
All works fine but now the performance drops significantly. But why?

I thought the bitmaps data whould be in cache with the changed color values so why should that affect performance?

How can i perhaps permanently apply a ColorFilter or in a other way tint the image so that it will treated the same as the original untinted image performance wise?

Comment: Are you applying a filter on tick? If you apply it once, it shouldn't cause performance issues, but if you change something and re-apply (using cache again), then it will likely slow right down.

Comment: The problem is that i draw a stroke as mask on stagemousemove. And i have to use: shape.updateCache(0,0,100,100); bmp.updateCache(0,0,100,100); beeing bmp the Bitmap with the filter to see any results with the grown mask. Strange also that it does not seem to make a difference if i update 100x100 or 500x500 pixels.

Comment: Yeah, updating a filter constantly is very expensive. The latest version 0.8.0 in GitHub (previously the NEXT version until today) has some awesome performance gains, and filters are running considerably faster. If you are using 0.7.1 or earlier, an update might give you a better experience.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look. But still i think i should be able to change the image data somehow to just have an bitmapArray out of which i create the easeljs Bitmap and good. Then the tint should have zero impact on the further computations. Just some more memory used.

Comment: If you apply a filter once (on image load), then cache it, the subsequent draws use the cached version, which will be fine on performance. If you are calling updateCache every tick, then the cache is redrawn every time. Check out the filters_animated example on GitHub, which shows this approach.